# certificate verify failed for mercurial VCS in teamcity

Tags: version-control, mercurial, certificate, teamcity

I am trying to configure mercurial with teamcity but getting the following error:

stderr: abort: error: _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

tried solutions mentioned in following link of signed certificates but nothing seems to be working.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CACertificates#Manually_bypassing_security_checks_on_self-signed_certificates

Any Idea what I am missing here. Please guide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix the problem by putting the mercurial.ini config file at C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile path.

Comment: I was having the same problem with the Mercurial plugin for the Jenkins CI system, but this solution worked.