# TeamCity and Mercurial https

Tags: ssl, https, mercurial, continuous-integration, teamcity

I try to connect from TeamCity to Mercurial repository over https.
But I can't, because appears error:
stderr: abort: error: _ssl.c:577: error: 14090086:SSL
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.
How can I disable sertificate verification by TeamCity?
Or how I can workaround this?
I have tried to load sertificate from IE and past it in cer file of Mercurial, but it is not resolve my issue.

Comment: Have you added path to certificate to hgrc file on server machine as described [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates#Configuration_of_HTTPS_certificate_authorities)?
See [related question](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-23150) and comments in TeamCity tracker.

Comment: Yes, I have, but it not solved my problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [certificate verify failed for mercurial VCS in teamcity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847213/certificate-verify-failed-for-mercurial-vcs-in-teamcity)

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my issue, only after put mercurial.ini in catalog C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.
Editing of .hgrc not take effect. Only putting mercurial.ini in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile and add loaded certificate to cacept.pem solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Better than disabling certificate verification (where possible) is to let Mercurial know that you trust the certificate. (This is a Windows-specific answer).

The thing I missed for ages is that **even if you import the certificate into the Trusted Root Certification Authority, this doesn't affect the Local System account**, which TeamCity is running under if you have set it up to run as a service.

The full steps to get the Local System account to trust a certificate are in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/830520/363680), but I'll reproduce them in brief here:

1. First, get a copy of the certificate. You can export this to a file from the all the main browsers.
2. Then, run mmc.exe from the start menu. Add the Certificates snap-in. If TeamCity is running as the local system account you want to manage "Local computer" certificates. If TeamCity is running as an ordinary user you want to manage user certificates.
3. Navigate to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". Then click "Action > All Tasks > Import" and import the certificate file.

A final note: You can use psexec.exe from [PSTools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pstools.aspx) to run powershell as Local System and test things are working before going back to TeamCity: [(Reference)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ben_parker/2010/10/27/how-do-i-run-powershell-execommand-prompt-as-the-localsystem-account-on-windows-7/)

```
psexec -i -s Powershell.exe
```